# How do I reset the postgresql 9.2 default user (usually 'postgres') password on mac os x 10.8.2?

Tags: macos, postgresql

I just installed `PostgreSQL 9.2` from [enterprisedb](http://www.enterprisedb.com/) onto `Mac OS X 10.8.2`. I mistyped my `postgres` user password, so I can't connect. How do I reset the password?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

[Found directions](http://visibletrap.blogspot.com/2011/12/postgresqlmac-modify-root-password.html):

```
sudo su postgres
```

modify /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/data/pg_hba.conf

```
-local all all   md5
+local all all   trust
```

restart postgres

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/pg_ctl restart -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/data/
```

Connect to postgres:

```
psql
```

Inside psql (`\q` to quit):

```
ALTER USER postgres WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'password';
```

modify pg_hba.conf back

```
+local all all   md5
-local all all   trust
```

restart postgres

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/pg_ctl restart -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/data/
```

Comment: There is no need to restart Postgres after changing pg_hba.conf. You just need to reload it using `pg_ctl reload`.

Comment: I had to set PG_DATA=`pwd`/data when I was in the right postgres root dir to be able to run pg_ctl restart.

Comment: in case su is not set up before on your mac then follow instructions from below to set it up.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012