# Unable to login to newly created database

Tags: postgresql

I created a `intranet` database, then logged out and stepped away from my PC for a few hours.  Now I'm back and I want to create a user for that database.  I tried to login to the database to create the new user and it's not letting me in.

```
# psql intranet postgres -W
Password for user postgres:
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Does the database user "postgres" share the same password as SSH?  I've changed the SSH user password, but not PostgreSQL.

**update**

I've verified I'm using the correct password for this user by typing in the same password my IDE is using.

Comment: Normally, the postgres passwords are distinct from the OS passwords. You can, however, configure postgres to use different passwords schemes, such as LDAP. This can be configured on a per database or per ip-range basis. See your pg_hba.conf.

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921380/how-do-i-reset-the-postgresql-9-2-default-user-usually-postgres-password-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by resetting the PostgreSQL password on the `postgres` user and then using that user to create a database-specific user.

```
 # su postgres
postgres@ProdSQL:~/data> psql
psql (9.1.9)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# ALTER USER postgres WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'ssV!mp8';
ALTER ROLE
postgres=# \q
postgres@ProdSQL:~/data> psql intranet postgres -W
Password for user postgres:
psql (9.1.9)
Type "help" for help.

intranet=# CREATE USER intranet LOGIN PASSWORD '********';
CREATE ROLE
intranet=#
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set up your server with "peer" authentication, which means that it expects you to log in as the "postgres" shell user.  That means you need to do this:

sudo su - postgres

psql intranet

If you want to use password authentication for the "postgres" user, then you should modify the pg_hba.conf file to set the authentication.

More here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html