# I dont know how Postgresql created user on my mac

Tags: postgresql, macos, terminal

Two days ago, i started learning postgresql. Most tutorials I followed online were either old or the codes wont just work on my mac. I followed a lot of tutorials that did a lot of totally different things.
When i switched on my system today. I noticed Postgresql created a user on my mac. I don't know what this is or maybe i used the wrong CLI code.

[image]

When I tried viewing the user, I saw this

[image]

should I delete this user or it has a function?

Comment: How did you install Postgres? I didn't have this happen when installing [via Homebrew, which Postgres recommends](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Homebrew).

Comment: I installed via homebrew. also installed homebrew too. Just wondering if i entered the wrong CLI code

Comment: Hard to say. What CLI code *did* you enter? `brew install postgres` shouldn't've caused this, I don't think.

Comment: This Question might have been better asked on the sister site, https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Basil Thanks, would do that.

Comment: @ceejayoz yeah thats what i typed

Comment: @Pelumi Regarding your confirmation of typing `brew install postgres`, post that kind of important detail as an edit to your Question rather than as a Comment. You should see an `edit` link or button where you can revise the text of your Question.

Comment: @BasilBourque I typed a lot of commands i cant remember. I followed different tutorials. But i think i got the answer now though.

Comment: FYI: See a related Question on uninstalling Postgres from macOS on the sister site: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/185476/19079

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## `postgres` user account

Creating a user account specifically for Postgres, commonly named `postgres`, is a normal part of a Postgres installation. Your installer app likely prompted you for a password to assign to this new user account.

One reason for this is **security**: The database’s data files and security configuration files are stored in folders owned by the `postgres` user. So if your main user account is hijacked, the intruder does not yet have access to the database (often the most valuable thing in storage). The intruder must jump through more hoops to compromise Postgres. Also, the separate ownership prevents other apps from inadvertently stomping on the Postgres files.

You will find Postgres is much more enterprise-oriented than other products such as MySQL. This means locking-down for security. Another example: Postgres by default is configured to *not* accept connections over the network. To enable connections from other computers, you must change the configuration. Inconvenient for the beginner, but more secure. Like a bar on your car steering wheel and deadbolts on your doors, more security always means more steps to take and more annoyance.

## Use a virtual machine

Installing the `postgres` user account is one of the things that makes Postgres a rather heavyweight installation. I suggest to those learning Postgres to use a virtual machine for Postgres. Something like:

- [Parallels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallels_Desktop_for_Mac) or [Fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Fusion) or [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) on your own computer
- Cloud server such as [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD) on [DigitalOcean.com](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigitalOcean).

To remove Postgres, simply discard the vm.

## *Postgres.app* for macOS

Another option for a Mac user is [*Postgres.app*](https://postgresapp.com), created by the person who built one of the first Postgres-as-a-Service implementations (on [Heroku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku)). I have not used *Postgres.app*, but I understand it wraps Postgres, so it does not install the `postgres` user account. Also, Postgres starts and stops when launch and quit the app, rather than running in the background all the time.

Be aware: you may have conflicts with Postgres.app on a Mac where you already have a conventional installation. I suggest you first carefully [remove the conventional Postgres from your Mac](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=uninstall%20postgres%20mac&t=osx&ia=web) before installing Postgres.app. Uninstalling involves finding and deleting various files and folders in various places.

## Database-as-a-Service (DBaaS)

Another option to avoid local installation is the increasing choices for running Postgres as a service. This is sometimes referred to as “managed Postgres” because the vendor maintains the installation of Postgres on your behalf. You simply *use* Postgres to create your database, but you do not fully *control* Postgres in such a service.

Some examples:

- [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/postgres)
- [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/managed-databases/)
- [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/postgresql/)
- [Amazon Web Services (AWS)](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/)
- [ElephantSQL](https://www.elephantsql.com)

## My experience

Personally, I often install Postgres on a Mac using the [installer by EnterpriseDB.com](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads). That company sells added-value versions of Postgres, but kindly provides an installer for plain-vanilla Postgres, as a service to the community.

I have also used that same installer from EnterpriseDB.com to install onto a Parallels VM running macOS as the guest OS within the VM on a MacBook Pro running macOS as the host OS. You can easily configure the VM to share the host Mac’s IP address on the network, or you can give the VM its own network address which might be handy for demo/dev/test work.

Thirdly, I have installed Postgres on FreeBSD on DigitalOcean.com.

All three of these options have worked quite well for me. Which is preferable depends on the scenario. For example, the DigitalOcean.com approach is good if I want colleagues to be able to reach the database 24x7 without my own MacBook being available.

This discussion is for development work. For mission-critical deployment, I strongly recommend using heavy-duty server equipment with [error-correcting memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory) and redundant storage such as [RAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) or [ZFS pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS). Postgres is extremely reliable but depends, of course, on reliable hardware.

---

Your tag says Postgres 9.1. That version is quite old now. I suggest using the latest version. By the way, the version numbering system has changed for postgres. The first number is now the roughly-annual release number likely requiring you to dump and reload data to upgrade, and the second number is compatible updates.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining this!!. But i already deleted this acct! What can i do?

Comment: @Pelumi Is this macOS? You might be able to recreate the account with the same name. Hopefully that would give the new user access to the existing Postgres-related files and folders. Or, you could follow the link I provided, to search for details on how to delete Postgres from your Mac. This is likely to be: (1) Run an uninstall-script left by your installer. (2) Manually deleting a few leftover files and folders in various nooks-and-crannies. Then you can re-install Postgres if desired, or use one of the alternatives I suggested. Sorry for your hassles, but Postgres is worth it (awesome db)!

Comment: @Pelumi So your added *new* user account with the same name `postgres` was given access by macOS to the existing Postgres-related folders and files? Please confirm or explain -- interesting to know.

Comment: I'm not so sure if it has access to the Postgres related files. I'm new to database. Everything still kind of sounds weird to me. But i added the account back manually. How do i know if it has access to them?

Comment: @Pelumi Either your Postgres works or it doesn't -- that will tell you. I suspect you be better off removing Postgres entirely as instructed in steps 1 & 2 of my comment above, and staring from scratch, but that is just a guess.

Comment: Oh if thats the case. My Postgres still work, even after removing the user. And seems like i installed Postgres with Brew and also downloaded it. Maybe thats why?

Comment: @Pelumi Sorry, I know nothing about *Brew*, can’t help you there.

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out by @basil-bourque, the account is required for several reasons.
That said, if it annoys you to have the PostgreSQL showing up in the login screen -as it did me-, you can remove it as long as you have admin user rights in MacOS.

[Apple Support gives](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT203998) the following command to hide a user from the login screen:

```
$ sudo dscl . create /Users/hiddenuser IsHidden 1
```

However, since the PostgreSQL user was not included listed in the login window at installation, that command will yield no result -at least in Catalina, which is my OS.
You should use the following two commands instead, as suggested by [josemarluedke](https://gist.github.com/josemarluedke/3090936):

```
## add postgres to the list of hidden users on login screen
$ sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow HiddenUsersList -array-add 'postgres'
## instruct not to show any hidden accounts at login
$ sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow SHOWOTHERUSERS_MANAGED -bool FALSE
```

Worked for me!