# postgres 9.2 forgot password

Tags: windows, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am very new to PostgreSQL, When I opened pgAdmin III and tried to **connect** with PostgreSQL 9.2 (x86) localhost

It asked me password of user openpg: (which we have forgotten)

I will appreciate if someone kindly help me to reset the password of our database (on Windows Platform) ?

Thanks & regards

Comment: If you have access to the db server, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921380/how-do-i-reset-the-postgresql-9-2-default-user-usually-postgres-password-on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reset the postgresql 9.2 default user (usually 'postgres') password on mac os x 10.8.2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921380/how-do-i-reset-the-postgresql-9-2-default-user-usually-postgres-password-on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the line on top:

```
local    postgres     postgres     trust
```

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.4\data\pg_hba.conf

restart/reload postgres...

login to postgres... authentication will not be required...

```
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'new_password';
```

where postgres is the username...

then finally edit the line we added at the beginning to...

```
local    postgres     postgres     md5
```

restart postgresql again... Now you should probably login using your new password you entered...

---

if the above doesn't work...
add the following to the configuration file pg_hba.conf...

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# IPv4 local connections:
host    postgres             postgres             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    postgres             postgres             ::1/128                 trust
```

then reload the configuration or restart the service...
now you could probably login without password...
change the password...

if that works... finally, do not forget to replace "trust" with "md5"...

Comment: Thanks Tomonso, How could I restart/reload posgtres ? I typed reload postgres on C:\ > but no internal or extral command message appeared

Comment: If you're using Windows, go to your "Services", look for "PostgreSQLxxxxxx", and *restart* that service.

Comment: Hi, I have tried, but couldn't get success. ( I am using Postgre in windows), when add this line       local    postgres     postgres     trust     in the top of pg_hba.conf     and restart postgressql service in windows service, it got an alert says: The posgres service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some service stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs. and in SQL Shall when i typed ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'new_password'; i got may ignored lines, Where exactly I have to type ALTER user command ? in SQL Shell ?

Comment: @Reyan if the above is not working for you... try this... comment all the line in the file "pg_hba.conf"... add this two lines... "host    postgres    postgres    127.0.0.1/32    trust"  "host    postgres    postgres    ::1/128    trust".... make sure all other lines are commented with "#"... then reload the conf file or restart services... i think that should work...

Comment: if that works... change the password... and finally do not forget  to  replace "trust" with "md5"...

Comment: Thanks Tomonso, appreciated for your reply! yes that worked for me and I have successfully changed the password. But as soon as I changed it my OpenERP software has stopped, after long research I got to know we need to change the same password in OpenERP-Server.conf file as well. So things are working fine now! thanks & regards